# How to make a string match to all other in android

Tags: android, firebase, if-statement

I want to enter into the true block of the **if** condition for any NAME in the following code. So how i can declare the string NAME to match it with all models.getName.

```
if(models.getName().equals(NAME))
```

I'm using this inside a loop along with other conditions like shown in below and the NAME does not contains a value all the type. So at the time when NAME is empty i need to skip that condition check. But need to check other two.

```
if(models.getName().equals(NAME)&&models.getType().equals(ClgType)&&models.getUniversity().equals(University))
```

Actually i'm using three spinners that used to filter the result from the firebase. That three spinners get text to the NAME,ClgType and University. Sometimes the user may not fill all the three fields. Since there is no way to use multiple orderByChild in firebase. I'm loading all the data from firebase and trying to filter the result from client side with the above code. If all the three conditions are satisfied then only result will be added to  recycler view. But the problem arises when the user selects only one or two spinner. At that point i need to filter the result with the one or two spinner that selected by user. At the time the third spinner will be empty, so i want the empty string from third spinner to be satisfied in the condition at the point only when the string is empty.

Comment: force the user to use 3 spinners, do like a condition if user does not select that spinner then show a toast "it needs to be selected" and return;

Comment: No way other than that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is so unclear at so many points but as far as I get your point, I am providing answer let me know if this is you want or not.

There is 'OR' condition also in if-else.
You can use '||' to perform 'OR' operation.

```
if((models.getName().equals('') || models.getName().equals(NAME))
&& (models.getType().equals('') || models.getType().equals(ClgType))
&& (models.getUniversity().equals('') || models.getUniversity().equals(University)))
```

**EDIT:**

Updating my code according to what I understood from your last comment.

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
  switch(arg0.getId()){
   case <Your spinner1 Id> :
         if(models.getName().equals('') || models.getName().equals(NAME)){

         }
         break;
   case <Your spinner2 Id> :
         if(models.getType().equals('') || models.getType().equals(ClgType)){

         }
   break;
   case <Your spinner3 Id> :
         if(models.getUniversity().equals('') || models.getUniversity().equals(University)){

         }
   break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I want all the conditions to be checked and satisfied to enter into the true part. But when any of the three strings is empty, It should check only other two.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what i actually meant with the question is that, Is there any pattern like [a-z]* available on android to represent all the strings. Because i can pass that pattern if any of the spinners is empty, so that it will make match with all.

Comment: @MohammedJavad Okay I updated the code Try it and let me know if this is what you want or not.